# How to send data to another computer via php?

Tags: php

I was wondering whether there is a way to send data from `index.php` opened on one computer to `index.php` opened on another one.
I don't have an idea how to do it.

Comment: If it's been opened on a different computer, then the PHP has already finished running on the server and you just have a DOM in a browser and will need to look at JavaScript if you want to do any programming.

Comment: *"one on computer"* - Intranet? Web Server? Question's unclear; we need details.

Comment: one way: `file_get_contents('http:\\www.google.com');`

Comment: There are a lot of ways. unfortunately none of them are secure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes.

**Easy/lazy way**: just do a remote get request

```
// example1.com/index.php 
file_get_contents("http://example2.com/index.php?your_data=goes_here");

// example2.com/index.php
$your_data = $_GET['your_data'];
```

**Harder/better** way: use curl to send a post request

```
// on example1.com/index.php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "http://example2.com/index.php");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'your_data' => 'goes_here');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// on example2.com/index.php
$your_data = $_POST['your_data'];
```

### **WARNING**: Anyone will be able to input anything they want into your scripts with either of these methods. Make sure to encrypt and/or validate any data you're transmitting in this way.

Comment: (You'll need the curl module for PHP installed if it isn't already by default. `apt install php-curl` on debian linux.)

Comment: You are assuming two domains example1.com and example2.com, OP said same file opened with different computers

Comment: *WELL THESE ARE MY HYPOTHETICAL DOMAINS*, so actually, you are assuming `example1.com` and `example2.com` aren't actually cname records that point to `host1.example.com` and `host2.example.com`.

The procedure is the same regardless of how you resolve the IP addresses, or whether they are 1 hop or 200 hops from each other. 

Same/different domain is an irrelevant distinction.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, assuming the computers are able to connect then the obvious way to do it is via HTTP:

```
<?php

$message="Hello otherhost!";
$response=file_get_contents("http://otherhost.example.com/?data=" 
  . urlencode($message));
print "I said \"$message\"<br />\nand other host replied \""
  . htmlentities($response) . "\"";
?>
```

---

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['data'])) {
     print "Hello - you just said \"" . htmlentities($_GET["data"]) . "\"";
} else {
     print "Sorry - I can't hear you";
}
?>
```